# jQuery doesn't get applied. Javascript works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What this should do: It adds a Class to the first Child. The second one is just for testing. It should change the background-color of one list-element to red.
None of those applies.

```
clientStuff();
alert("Hi");

function clientStuff(){
  $('.client-unit').first().addClass('active-client');
}

$( "li" ).first().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

What i've tried:

1. I checked the linking of the documents. And their order. Here comes the linking:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

2. I checked the semicolons and for spelling mistakes.
3. I asked mighty Cthulu for help. He said "no."

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: is it inside a `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: Have you asked Mighty DevConsole?

Comment: can you post your html too, please?

Comment: ...And have you defined `$`. Also, mighty Cthulu requires a sacrificial offering from you first before consenting to offer any assistance.

Comment: Please post HTML

Comment: mighty Cthulhu probably prefers to be spelt correctly too.

Comment: Maybe the spelling mistake is the reason Cthulhu didn't help. Please don't tell him. No I didnt ask Mighty DevConsole. The solution was the missing $(document).ready(). Thank you @Angel for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```js
$(function(){

  var $li = $('ul li').click(function() {
    $li.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
li.selected {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Try this, If you need to **select only first child**:

```
$('ul li:first')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check this, I Hope its helpful to you**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <link href="styles.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**In script.js file like that below :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert("Hi");
     clientStuff();
     $( "li" ).first().css( "background-color", "red" );

});
function clientStuff(){
    $('.client-unit').first().addClass('active-client');
}
```

Comment: I'd like to give you a brofirst and a cookie. It works. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

$( "li" ).first().css({"background-color": "yellow"});

Answer (score 0):

Actually **first()** attribute does not apply to child attributes rather it applies to first of it's own kind,

Therefore the **first()** searches for first **element which has class** **client-unit** and applies class to that,

Here is the sample screenshot of the output : [image: screenshot]

Also here is the Codepen of your code, with sample HTML from my side,

https://codepen.io/shohil06/pen/ZJzEJj

Hope it helps !

Thank You

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using Jquery.

so use like that code it will work.

```
    jQuery(function(){
      $('.client-unit').first().addClass('active-client');
      $('li').first().css("background-color","red");
    });
```